# Non-optional of type... better way to say this?

Tags: swift

Optionals are obviously a fundamental feature of Swift, and a little mealy in their own right, both in terms of their naming and description and processes.

But Non-optional of type: surely there's a better way to make it clear that something is of a type and NOT an Optional, both in conversation and documentation.

Obviously "literal" is the wrong kind of word for this, since it's so heavily used for literal values, but is there another way anyone's seen to describe a Non-optional of type that's easy on the eyes, ears and mind?

Comment: Ehm, a "required"? :)

Comment: How about a "safe", it's safe that this variable is set, and non nil.

Comment: In the [official document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID309), "nonoptional" is used for that. *"`nil` cannot be used with nonoptional constants and variables."*, *"An implicitly unwrapped optional ... can also be used like a nonoptional value ..."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a value is optional it should be clear from context in many cases.

There is also no official naming convention how optionals and non-optionals should be named. On WWDC 14 they also explicitly said it is easy to find out the type of a value with Xcode's quick look feature (Option+Left click or 3 finger tap on trackpads).

So a naming convention would be a personal preference.

Here are some prefixes you could use to mark variables as optionals:

- optional
- maybe
- couldBe
- probably

non-optionals:

- nonNil
- definitely
- some (`Optional` is an enum with two cases: `.Some` and `.None`)
- (unwrapped)

All in all you should rather make a naming convention for optionals than non-optionals since they are the exception.

Comment: actually a non-optional is **not** unwrapped because it has never been wrapped nor it's `some` because it is definitely not an optional.

Comment: @vadian You are right. I've put "unwrapped" in parenthesis. However `.Some` stands for a value / not nil in context of `Optional`. Either way, you have to make clear that you are using a naming convention and more importantly for what.

Comment: But a non-optional is not a enum type, `some` and `none` represent `has a wrapped value` and `has no value` only for optional types.

Comment: @vadian As I said it is also personal preference where I could imagine to use "some" as prefix for non-optionals.

Comment: Might be but it's ambiguous with an optional containing a wrapped value.

Comment: @vadian Therefore the convention (which has to be made clear) to make such situation unambiguous. Even though the name itself would be ambiguous without more context.